# What should be the query for setting foreign key to zero in sql server r2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`

for My sql but i need the same query in Sql Server, I tried this

`ALTER TABLE MyTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;`

but its not working for me somehow. Can anybody tell me how to write

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`

same query in sql server?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Do you see an error when you try and insert something into the table? does the error mention to constraint or the table? Never write 'not working'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
      NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
GO


INSERT INTO MyTable
...


ALTER TABLE MyTable
    CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
GO
```

You can check then if any keys violate the constraints...

```
DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS('MyTable')
GO
```